# Laravel 5 Can not get authenticated user from view

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am trying to use laravel authentication service.

The problem is I can successfully register a new user and redirect to the successful page. Nevertheless, I can not get the authenticated user within the successful page.

Below is showing what have done so far.

**view**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/auth/register">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('first_name') }}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Register
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**User Model（register_info）**

```
 /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'register_info';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','username', 'email', 'password','city'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

**Controller:**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * When a user is successfully authenticated
     * they will be redirected to $redirectPath
     */
    protected $redirectPath = 'manybotest';

    /**
     * When a user is not successfully authenticated
     * they will be redirected to the $loginPath
     */
    protected $loginPath = '/login';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     *
     * 'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:register_info',
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'user_id' => uniqid('us'),
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
  Route::get('manybotest', function () {
        $users = Auth::user();
        return view('manybotest',compact('users'));
    });
```

**Display view(manybotest.blade.php):**

```
  <?php

        var_dump(Session::all());
        var_dump(Auth::check());
        var_dump(Auth::user());
        var_dump(Auth::id());
        var_dump($users);

    ?>
```

**Result:**

```
login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc => int 0//Session::all()
boolean false//Auth::check()
null//Auth::user()
int 0//Auth::id()
null//$users passed by routes
```

**Question:**

I can get the user id from session. Why can't I get the authenticated user? 
I also try to inspect the inner code of laravel, the user was already set by laravel.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to register the user (i.e. for the the `/auth/register` route)?

Comment: Where's your login page?

Comment: @JamesFlight i use the laravel register service. I have shown the register code as above in controller

Comment: @aldrin27 manybotest.blade.php is my login page

Comment: Stupid question to ask, but are you sure that you are logged in?

Comment: @blackpla9ue If i were right, after successfully register, laravel will login automatically by calling laravel Auth "login" method, which has done all the login work.

Comment: Thanks so much @aldrin27, the problem has solved. If you are interested, please see the answer posted below

Comment: Thanks so much @Janes Flight, the problem has solved. If you are interested, please see the answer posted below

Comment: Wow. + 1 for you then. :D

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved:**

The main problem is that my user table id is customized which is not a auto_increment id.

After adding **public $incrementing = false**; to my user model. The problem solved.

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;


    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'register_info';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','username', 'email', 'password','city'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    /**
     * Get the bonding UserDetail
     *
     * @return UserDetail
     */
    public function getUserDetail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\UserDetail','user_id','user_id');
    }

}
```

**Problem analysis:**
In laravel, by default the id of model user is set as auto-increment. If we use customized user_id like i do.

```
 /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'user_id' => uniqid('us'),
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
        ]);
    }
```

The returned model will contain a auto-increment id. What i got is always 0. Therefore, a User instance with id 0 is stored in laravel. When i call Auth:user(), we will get null instead of the User instance.

```
{"user_id":"0","username":"xxxxx@gmail.com","password":"xxxxxxx"}
```

After adding **public $incrementing = false**; to my user model. I can get my user instance correctly with id that i defined.

```
{"user_id":"us55f7e7afbe87f","username":"xxxxx@gmail.com","password":"xxxxxxx"}
```

Hope this can be helpful.

Thanks everyone helped before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject `Guard` and `Register` in to the constructor.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }
```

If you look at [AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php), you can see that in the `postRegister` method, `login` is called on `$this->auth`.

Comment: Thanks so much @blackpla9ue, the problem has solved. If you are interested, please see the answer posted below.